# preview with tkinter of a pillow low resolution picture

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I want to open a new window with tkinter and pillow, that only displays one image.
In the following code I just displayed [the 16x16 image](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/709140374345482270/792719232886374410/213.png), but it is too small.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

image = Image.open('213.png')

root = Tk()


image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
panel1 = Label(root, image = image1)

panel1.grid()
root.mainloop()
```

[Click here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/709140374345482270/792718978959147058/Bildschirmfoto_2020-12-27_um_12.41.21.png) too see the window

Then I tried to resize the image with the following code

```
image = image.resize((250, 250))
```

But then the picture in the window gets very blurred.

[Click here](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/709140374345482270/792720278861905930/Bildschirmfoto_2020-12-27_um_12.47.02.png) to see the window

I'am trying to display the image [like this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/709140374345482270/792720939640422450/Bildschirmfoto_2020-12-27_um_12.49.29.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the `resample` option when calling `resize()`:

```py
image = Image.open('213.png').resize((250,250), Image.NEAREST)
```